# Sharepoint Libraries

Tags: document-library

We are looking at how best to design our Sharepoint 2013 and I have a few questions re Libraries.

We are a Public Sector business- and have 7 main Business areas (Adult and Children services, Environment, Transport, etc.) I am considering that they each have a site collection and each department in each business area has its own team site. Adult and Children Services (ACS) have an Adoption team so we would have a Site Collection for ACS and Adoption would have a team site.

I'm wondering if the following is possible:

Each Team Site will have one or more libraries specific to its needs. So Adoption Tem Site could for example have 3 Libraries: Adoption Applications / Adoption Policies / Adoption Case Files (I'm making these up but hope it makes sense).

One big reason I am considering this set up is because the business currently use government defined taxonomy and this is how the current document file plan is structured. So users are familiar with putting docs in correct folders however I am not suggesting a library is created for each folder but rather for each major category.

Scenario 1: User creates a brand new doc using MS Word and then drops it into the Sharepoint team library.

Q1: Is it possible that the library can restrict docs being added if they do not have mandatory tags applied? I.e. can libraries be created that restrict what can be added? For example you can’t add a document to the library if an Adoption Application case worker has not been assigned.

Q2: Is it possible that when a doc is added to a library that Meta tags are applied automatically to the doc based on predefined tags for that library. So for example if I drop a doc in the Adoption Applications library then that doc is assigned a specific taxonomy classification, id sequence value etc. This means users don’t have to repeatedly assign tags.
I know the ideal is to use to doc templates so that correct docs are used and correct attributes defined. However (even with Governance to say not to) it is possible that users will till try and create docs from scratch and put them in the libraries.  I am trying to minimise user input when adding a doc to a library. 
Q3: Are libraries the right way to go (remember users are familiar with existing taxonomy and folder structure).

Q4. Is there a rule of thumb as to the number of libraries on a team site?
Q5. IS there a max capacity for a library?

Q6 Can permissions/restrictions be applied at library level?

Q7. Can a library be made accessible to another team site?  Ie can a library be ‘shared’ across team sites?

Q8. Can the action of dropping a doc into a folder trigger a basic workflow?

I know there are a lot of questions – I am researching this topic but thought there may be people who have experience and could give some advice. Any help is really appreciated. Thank you. Adam

Answer (score 1):

I will try to respond to your questions:

Q1: yes, you can do that work with an event receiver, during the itemAdding event. (check if the document has some properties).
[Event Receiver SP2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx)

Q2: yes, you can define some default field values (so all the documents added to that library will have that fields)

[Default column values](https://www.collaboris.com/blogs/collaboris-blog/policy-management/2013/02/27/how-to-set-default-column-values-on-a-document-in-sharepoint)

Q3: yes, libraries can represent the folder structure. (folders and flies)
[Document library folder](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/create-a-document-library-folder-RZ010233836.aspx?section=6)

Q4,Q5: take a look here: [Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx)
(30k documents for library)

Q6: yes you can set a custom permission for a list and for each single item

[Edit permissions for a list, library, or individual item](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-permissions-for-a-list-library-or-individual-item-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Q7: you can share library among site collections and web sites

Q8: yes, event receiver is the solution

Hope this will help you.